# Show a certain number of text characters

Tags: javascript, text

I want to reduce the text so that only displays 30 characters
Like
`<p>Piqued favour stairs it enable exeter as seeing</p>`
I want to be a text `<p>Piqued favour stairs it...</p>`

using javascript

("Show a certain number of text characters")

Comment: What about using CSS?  Something like this - https://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the answer to your question:

```js
const trim = (data, len) =>
    data.replace(/(<(\w+)[^>]*?>)(\w.*?)<\/\2>/g,
        match => match.replace(/(?=>).*(?=<\/)/,
            match => match.length > len ? match.substr(0, len) : match
        ))

console.log(trim(`<div class="blog_contents"><h3 id="foo123">Facebook launches the application of a special communication companies</h3></div> `, 20))
```

Comment: It is this way                                                                                                                                                                        <div class="blog_contents"><h3 id="foo123">Facebook launches the application of a special communication companies</h3></div>                                                                        I want to reduce the number of letters the title to become so (<h3 id = "foo123"> Facebook launches the application of a special ... </ h3>)

Comment: Title not one but more than 5
I want to link

Comment: You want to do this on server side ?

Comment: Yes, my dear brother

Comment: Check is now it works for you.

Comment: Is a script addresses displays the titles and I want to lose a number of     look at the picture [link](http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148682229118981.png)

Comment: You mean just shorter without replace ?

Comment: @عبداللهمنقوش please have a look

Comment: I want him to run automatically without the replacement or add

Comment: what do you mean by saying automatically? Explain how you want to use it

Answer (score 1):

This is may be the most simple answer I can give using vanilla JS. It should work for you. Let me know, if not.

```js
const trimSize = 20;
let text = '<p>Something that is too big and you want to trim, and then renddeer in your HTML page.</p>';

let content = text.substring(3, text.length - 4);

let trimmedText = '<p>' + content.substring(0, trimSize) + '<\p>';
console.log(trimmedText);
```

Comment: It is this way                                                                                                                                                                        <div class="blog_contents"><h3 id="foo123">Facebook launches the application of a special communication companies</h3></div>                                                                        I want to reduce the number of letters the title to become so (<h3 id = "foo123"> Facebook launches the application of a special ... </ h3>)

Comment: Title not one but more than 5
I want to link